# Use of reference in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing code to solve the "Recover Binary Search Tree" problem.

https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/recover-binary-search-tree/

And first I wrote this code to put three pointers out of the **recoverTree** function like this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode *pre;
    TreeNode *first;
    TreeNode *second;

    void recoverTree(TreeNode *root) {

        inOrder(root);
        int temp = first->val;
        first->val = second->val;
        second->val = temp;
        return;
    }

    void inOrder(TreeNode *root) {
        if (!root) return;
        inOrder(root->left);
        if (!pre) {
            pre = root;
        } else {
            if (pre->val > root->val) {
                if (!first) first = pre;
                second = root;
            }
            pre = root;
        }
        inOrder(root->right);
    }

};
```

It works fine and past all the tests. And then I was thinking maybe not putting the definitions of three pointers outside the function. So I wrote something like this:

```
class Solution {
public:

    void recoverTree(TreeNode *root) {
        TreeNode *pre;
        TreeNode *first;
        TreeNode *second;
        inOrder(root, pre, first, second);
        int temp = first->val;
        first->val = second->val;
        second->val = temp;
        return;
    }

    void inOrder(TreeNode *root, TreeNode *&pre, TreeNode *&first, TreeNode *&second) {
        if (!root) return;
        inOrder(root->left, pre, first, second);
        if (!pre) {
            pre = root;
        } else {
            if (pre->val > root->val) {
                if (!first) first = pre;
                second = root;
            }
            pre = root;
        }
        inOrder(root->right, pre, first, second);
    }

};
```

But this doesn't work. Is there anything wrong with my usage of reference or anything else caused the error?

Comment: It's more than a little unusual to see references to pointers, and even more strange to see someone try and make a pointer to a reference. What are you trying to do here? It's also worth flagging any arguments that aren't manipulated as `const`.

Comment: Are you sure you need references to the pointers, or do you just want references to the nodes? Using both `*` and `&` is quite different from just `TreeNode &`.